# How to parse JSON using (Inline) JavaScript in Camunda BPM

Tags: javascript, json, camunda

I am trying to get the value from `statusAprovacao`, that is "Pre aprovado", but when I use the script `var list = json.prop("statusAprovacao");` the result is empty. What is the right way to query this value using JavaScript?

The script I tried:

```
var json = S(response);
var list = json.prop("statusAprovacao");
```

the result:

> SPIN/JACKSON-JSON-01004 Unable to find 'statusAprovacao'/

Json Script:

```
[{"statusAprovacao":{"type":"String","value":"Pre aprovado","valueInfo":{}},"analisar":{"type":"Boolean","value":true,"valueInfo":{}}}]
```

Comment: Ummm `var list = json[0]["statusAprovacao"];`

Comment: What is this: `S(response)`? What lib are you using to parse JSON? Why not just `JSON.parse`?

Comment: `SPIN/JACKSON-JSON-01004` I'm afraid, are you trying to use third-party libraries to parse JSON in the language it's native to? Just in case, JSON means JavaScript Object Notation...

Comment: S(response) is the standard used at the Camunda BPM, that I am using to make this query.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar To be fair to the downvoters, the asker did not mention Camunda at all in the title nor in question body. So it would be confusing. The only hint was `camunda` in the tags. So I fixed the title, to get better SEO too, as the answers are fortunately helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the elements you should call `elements()` method to get the array object.

Try this.

```
var json = S(response);
var list = json.elements().get(0).prop("statusAprovacao")
```

Answer (score 2):

Camunda Spin is a wrapper around Jackson that Camunda provides for JSON (and XML) processing. While I find it very helpful for processing JSON in Java, I prefer processing JSON natively within JavaScript (in Nashorn in this case). Your mileage may vary. :) Here's an example illustrating how to process the JSON natively in Nashorn, assuming `response` is stringified JSON:

```
var responseObj = JSON.parse(response);
var statusAprovacao = responseObj.statusAprovacao;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try:

```
    var list = json.Parse("type":"String","value":"Pre aprovado","valueInfo":{});
```

and then you get the value with

```
    list.value
```

Comment: but how can I get this script dinamically? It can't be hardcoded.